# PHP / MySql: Select DISTINCT certain columns does not give access to other columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Say I got the following database:

```
id name value other
1 Dave 340 otherinfo
2 Dave 340 otherinfo
3 Mike 350 otherinfo
```

I only want the rows that have unique name AND value, so I use this sql statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 'name', 'value' from TABLE
```

No I got the rows that I want (1 and 3), but I cannot access the other columns.
So $row[name] and $row[value] give me the info I selected, but for instance $row[other] gives NULL. How do I select those columns as well?

Comment: What would the desired result look like?

Comment: You have to either specify the columns you want or use `*`. Also `GROUP BY` syntax gives you much more control than `DISTINCT`.  Finally the current code is going to give you the literal string `'name'` and `'value'` ... they should be unquoted

Comment: The code is dummy code, I will try the Group By suggestion.

Comment: @Cuchu No it isn't, and neither is swearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just making my comment an answer.

First you don't want your column names quoted and secondly if you want other columns you just specify them:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, value, other FROM your_table
```

That said `DISTINCT` is applied to all the columns specified so it may not be what you want. You'll get more control by using `GROUP BY`. This query would give you the same thing as above:

```
SELECT name, value, other FROM your_table GROUP BY name, value, other
```

Or if you wanted to get rows that are distinct name and return the other columns

```
SELECT name, value, other FROM your_table GROUP BY name
```

Comment: The `DISTINCT` keyword applies to *all* of the expressions in the `SELECT` list, not just the first column.

Comment: @spencer7593 you are correct. I have fixed my examples

Answer (score 0):

You can use a derived table

```
DECLARE @thetable TABLE (id int, [name] varchar(100), [values] int, other varchar(100))
INSERT INTO @thetable VALUES (1, 'Dave', 340, 'otherinfo'), (2, 'Dave', 340, 'otherinfo'), (3, 'Mike', 350, 'otherinfo')

SELECT TT.*
  FROM (
        SELECT MIN(id) [minID] --take the minID by name, values
             , [name], [values]
          FROM @thetable
        GROUP BY [name], [values]
       ) AS dT INNER JOIN @thetable TT ON dT.minID = TT.id 
               --rejoin the derived output by minID = @thetable.id
```

Produces:

```
id  name    values  other
1   Dave    340     otherinfo
3   Mike    350     otherinfo
```

Comment: While this will work, it will also be very slow and it's very complex for what OP wants to do.

Comment: @Cfreak I'll agree, there's certainly a different way to do it, such as take MIN(id) after taking DISTINCT.  The idea was to give access to every column since OP was complaining about "losing columns".